Python Script with Multithreading and CAN Bus Communication Does Not Terminate
I am working on a Python script that sets up communication between multiple Electronic Control Units (ECU1 and ECU2) using the python-can library. The script is designed to read messages from a BLF file, filter them based on specific IDs, and handle them using separate threads for each ECU. However, the script does not terminate as expected and seems to get stuck after printing "main_ECU done","filtering done","ECU1 Thread has finished".
script flow:

main_ecu fucntion - reads the message and send to virtual bus
ecu_filter function - filter the messages based on ID and stop when ID 'oxDE0Q is Received
'main' function - create virtual bus, use threading as shown below

def main():
    bus = can.interface.Bus(interface='virtual', channel='0', bitrate=500000,receive_own_messages=True)

    can_id_filter_ecu1 = [0xKEREE, 0xWJKL0, oxDE0Q]
    can_id_filter_ecu_2 = [0xIOBF, oxDE0Q]

    main_ECU(bus, "input.blf")
    #two seperate threads for ecu 1 and ecu 2
    ecu_thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=ecu_filter,args= (bus,can_id_filter_ecu1,"File_1_msg.asc",))
    ecu_thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=ecu_filter, args=(bus,can_id_filter_ecu_2,"File_2_msg.asc",))

    ecu_thread_1.start()
    ecu_thread_2.start()

    ecu_thread_1.join()
    print("ECU1 Thread has finished.")
    ecu_thread_2.join()
    print("ECU2 Thread has finished.")
    bus.shutdown()

update
now the script runs and there is a value error and donot terminate: ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256) for the line(added below) included in the fucntion ecu_filter
response_msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=msg_id,data= bytearray([count]), is_extended_id=False)
a snippet of ecu_filter fucntion is as below:
def ecu_filter(bus, filter_ids, asc_file):
    stop_break = False
    log_ecu = can.ASCWriter(asc_file)
    msg_count = {}

    while not stop_break:
        mesg = bus.recv(1)
        print(mesg)  # Debugging output
        if mesg is not None and mesg.arbitration_id in filter_ids:
            log_ecu.log_event(mesg)
            if mesg.arbitration_id == oxDE0Q:
                stop_break = True
            elif mesg.arbitration_id in msg_count:
                msg_count[mesg.arbitration_id] += 1
            else:
                msg_count[mesg.arbitration_id] = 1
        for msg_id, count in msg_count.items():
            response_msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=msg_id, data=bytearray([count]), is_extended_id=False)
            bus.send(response_msg)
    log_ecu.stop()


output
main_ECU done
filtering done
ECU1 Thread has finished.

From the shown information it can only be concluded that ecu_filter doesn't return for ECU2. You can use a debugger or add print calls in ecu_filter to gather more information.

@MichaelButscher i added the ecu_filter function and have an error: ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)

It seems that some mesg.arbitration_id is received more than 255 times.

both the ECU's are using same input data and while printing the message received by ECU2 is always None, which i didnt undersatnd why!
